# uploadify php mysql - bulk upload and bulk insert

Tags: php, mysql, uploadify, bulkinsert

I am using uploadify to upload pictures into server . Back end I am using PHP script . In PHP script I am inserting the file location and some other details in database in addition to copying to target location .

**Problem :-** If I am uploading 20 files , the PHP script is getting called 20 times and the database insert statement are getting called 20 times to insert for different images . Definitely calling database 20 times is inefficient way of doing it .  Is there any way I can hold the file names( and location)  and call the insert statement (in the end)  only once to insert all the 20 records at once ?

Thanks for your help

Regards

Kiran

Comment: show your query, you can insert multiple values in mysql in one query and your script con run in a loop until it upload all files

Comment: thanks @lbu for your comment . here the problem is not with sql query . Keeping the 20 file names and locations in some temporary location .But uploadify is not supporting sessions ( as per my understanding )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach I recommend for this is the use of a prepared statement through the `mysqli` extension. To quote on the main advantage:

> The actual purpose to use a prepared
> statement in sql is to cut the cost of
> processing queries; NOT to separate
> data from query. That's how it's being
> used w/ php NOW, not how it was
> designed to be used in the first
> place. With SQL you cut the cost of
> executing multiple similar queries
> down by using a prepared statement..
> Doing so cuts out the parsing,
> validation and most often generates an
> execution plan for said query up
> front. Which is why they run faster in
> a loop, than their  IMMEDIATE Query
> cousins do.

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#103730

To give an example on how you can utilize this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `images` (`location`, `size`, `othervalues`) VALUES(?, ?, ?)")) {
  foreach($images as $image) {
    // s = string value
    // i = integer value
    $stmt->bind_param("sis", $image['location'], $image['size'], $image['othervalues']);
    $stmt->execute();
  }
  $stmt->close();
}
// Your prepared statement failed, handle the error
else {
}

$mysqli->close();
```

I'd recommend reading up on [mysqli::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#103730) and [mysqli_stmt::bind_param](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) for more information on how the process works. I also recommend reading up on [prepared statements in the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html).

Comment: Thanks @onteria_ for your response . Here the issue is I don't even have the Image array also . If I have image array sure I can write a mysqli batch insert to execute it once . Since the PHP is called for ever file , I get only the current file name . Some how I have to store all the file temporarily . But uploadify is not supporting sessions ( as per my understanding )